# c# An error occurred while parsing EntityName

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

An error occurred while parsing EntityName error.

I found a lot of information, but it was not helpful in any way.

I need help as detailed

```
        XmlDocument ReadInDocument = new XmlDocument();
        ReadInDocument.XmlResolver = null;
        ReadInDocument.Load("http://abone.iha.com.tr/yeniabone/RSS2.aspx?Kategori=3");

        foreach (XmlNode node in ReadInDocument.SelectNodes(".//rss/channel/item"))
        {
            SqlCommand komut1 = new SqlCommand("Select*from gelenhaberler where HaberKodu=@HaberKodu", strConnString);
            komut1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HaberKodu", node.SelectSingleNode("HaberKodu").InnerText);
            SqlDataReader oku = komut1.ExecuteReader();
            if (oku.HasRows)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = strConnString;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HaberKodu", node.SelectSingleNode("HaberKodu").InnerText);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sehir", node.SelectSingleNode("Sehir").InnerText);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", Capitalize(node.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", node.SelectSingleNode("description").InnerText);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pubDate", Convert.ToDateTime(node.SelectSingleNode("pubDate").InnerText));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@link", node.SelectSingleNode("link").InnerText);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
            komut1.Dispose();
            oku.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Share more information about the 'error' (the exception, the message, the line etc.) and please format your code.

Comment: An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line36, position 56

Comment: We would need to know more information.  1)  What is the full `ToString()` output of the exception?  At what line of your code does it occur?  2) What is the XML that is causing the problem?  If I direct my browser to http://abone.iha.com.tr/yeniabone/RSS2.aspx?Kategori=3  I see a web page displaying: "Müşteri Bilgisi IP üzerinden bulunamadı. [ İstek Yapan IP = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ]" -- this is not XML at all.